# How to read .docx file in R or convert it into .txt file?

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm trying to read CV. But can't find a way to read .docx file as plain text or convert it into text file.

Comment: You will probably have to use some sort of interop like `Office.Interop`. The `.docx` is a proprietary layout.

Comment: read_docx from qdapTools package does the job. Thanks anyways

Comment: excellent. glad you found a solution. please, post an answer and provide any links to documentation or downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_docx from qdapTools package does the job

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdapTools/versions/1.3.3/topics/read_docx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `docxtractr` package? Install if you don't have it and try it.

Comment: It only fetches the tables and comments from doc...I want to read it as plain text.